How many pods may use the same federated credentials to access a managed identity?
Is there a limit on how many pods may use the same federated credentials?
Let's say I have 5 pods that all use the same service account. The service account is annotated with azure.workload.identity/client-id and on the Azure side, I have a federated credential for this service account to a managed identity.
Should this work?
I ask because I am getting a lot of errors like:
Azure Identity => ERROR in getToken() call

...

Attempted credential WorkloadIdentityCredential is unavailable.


It's not an issue with the issuer, audience, or subject.
The JWT mounted to /var/run/secrets/azure/tokens/azure-identity-token is valid when I decode it.
I am just looking to know if the many-to-one relationship here should work or not.
Also. There is another set of 5 pods that have a different service account and federated credential to the same UMI.
In summary,

10 pods
2 service accounts
2 federated credentials
1 UMI

There are 5 pods per svc_acct/fed_cred combo. Both svc_acct/fed_cred combos access the same UMI. All 10 pods access the same UMI.

NOTE: AWS EKS doesn't have this issue, because unlike Azure, the token subject does not have to be an exact match. Something like the following works for AWS:
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "Federated": "arn:aws:iam::111122223333:oidc-provider/oidc.eks.region-code.amazonaws.com/id/EXAMPLED539D4633E53DE1B71EXAMPLE"
            },
            "Action": "sts:AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity",
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "oidc.eks.region-code.amazonaws.com/id/EXAMPLED539D4633E53DE1B71EXAMPLE:sub": "system:serviceaccount:default:*",
                    "oidc.eks.region-code.amazonaws.com/id/EXAMPLED539D4633E53DE1B71EXAMPLE:aud": "sts.amazonaws.com"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/associate-service-account-role.html

Yes, multiple pods can use the same federated credentials to access a managed identity in Azure. There is no inherent limit on the number of pods that can share the same federated credentials.

The error you are encountering Azure Identity => ERROR in getToken() call … Attempted credential WorkloadIdentityCredential is unavailable.suggest potential issues in your setup.

Double check the azure.workload.identity/client-id annotation on your service accounts.Ensure it matches the corresponding client ID in the federated credential on the Azure side.
If your pods have security context constraints or pod security policies that restrict access to Azure identity tokens or secrets adjust these policies accordingly.
Verify that the managed identity associated with the federated credential has the necessary Azure AD roles to access the desired resources.

As you correctly noted AWS EKS allows for more flexibility in token subject matching making it more tolerant of minor service account name variations. Azure enforces a stricter match.
While AWS EKS offers more flexibility in token subject matching, use this feature with caution and ensure adequate IAM permissions.

you are right about the difference in subject matching between AWSEKS and Azure AD.while Azure AD requires an exact match between the token subject and the service account name,AWS EKS allows for wildcards in the subject claim.This can be more flexiable in some scenarios

Refer to this official doc about Use Microsoft Entra Workload ID with Azure Kubernetes Service (AKS)

Hi @SaiChandiniRouthu. It is helpful to know that there is no inherent limit on the number of pods that can share the same federated credentials. I have double-checked the setup. The annotation on the service account is correct. The federated credentials and the role assignment for the UMI are correct. I will investigate the security context restraints. I will work with my team and Azure to get the problem resolved.

If you are not using the latest Azure identity client library for your programming language. consider upgrading newer versions might have error fixes that address token retrieval issues.

While sharing federated credentials is not inherently limited,excessive token requests from numerous pods can strain Azure identity services. so,Implement a caching mechanism in your application code to reuse tokens for a reasonable duration

Refer to this doc about Azure Identity Plugin for Token Cache Persistence

@ Matthiasdenu Let me know whether your issue is resolved or not

@ Matthiasdenu If you have any further queries let me know

@ Matthiasdenu  I am looking forward to your feedback to understand whether the provided resolution has helped you in resolving the issue. If not, I am happy to assist further.

Azure didn't correctly register the fed cred on creation. Deleting the old fed cred and recreating it worked.

A lot of time was spent triple-checking configurations, pouring over documentation, and asking around. Deleting and recreating the fed cred at the advice of one of the reps finally resolved the issue. Azure didn't correctly register the fed cred on creation. I don't think it's something that happens often.
